# sql query to list a table content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a view for following table data using an SQL query.

```
  empid  Name     Managerid

  1     Vinoth     Null

  2      Raja        1

  3      Ramu        6

  4      Ramesh      6

  5      Rajini      1

  6      Billa     Null
```

I want to display the above table content in the style below:

```
  empid  Name     Managerid

  1     Vinoth     Null

  2      Raja        1


  5      Rajini      1

  6      Billa     Null 

  3      Ramu        6

  4      Ramesh      6
```

Tell me how to create a view to get this output.

Answer (score 2):

Why all the negative votes?  User is requesting a depth-first ordering of a hierarchical relationship.

So if the data is in table #t (replace with your table name):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  empid, Name, Managerid, CAST(empid as varchar(max)) + '|' AS Ordering
    FROM    #t
    WHERE   Managerid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  #t.empid, #t.Name, #t.Managerid, cte.Ordering + CAST(#t.empid AS VARCHAR(MAX))  + '|'
    FROM    cte
            JOIN #t ON cte.empid = #t.Managerid 
)
SELECT  empid, Name, Managerid 
FROM    cte
ORDER BY Ordering;
```

Comment: `Why all the negative votes?` My guess is because they didn't show any effort.  Good answer, all the same.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables true... i forget that questioners should at least show a little effort.  I liked the question just the same :)

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki thanks for your answer .
but i was tried to create a view using above query .i was not able to create a view .
i got below error message...
"  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AgentDetailsForSearch, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ';'.  " message

Comment: @Vinoth CTEs were introduced in SQL 2005.  What version are you using?  If it's 2005 or later, then the above code works, and I would say you need to just debug your stored proc.  As a coder, you should have the ability to locate the source of a syntax error.